# Cant put path of certificate to antora-playbook.yml

Tags: gitlab, certificate, antora

thats the content of my antora-playbook.yml in my documents project:

```
runtime:
  cache_dir: ./.cache/antora
site:
 title: Dokumentation "My App"
 start_page: component-a::index.adoc
content:
 sources:
  - url: https://gitlab.x.info/myapp/app.git
    branches: asciidoc-GitLab
    start_path: docs
 asciidoc:
   attributes:
   experimental: ''
   idprefix: ''
   idseparator: '-'
   page-pagination: ''
   source-language: asciidoc@
  ui:
   bundle:
   url: https://gitlab.com/antora/antora-ui-default/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/build/ui-bundle.zip? 
   job=bundle-stable
   snapshot: true
```

it is not possible to include a gitlab certificate like:

```
git:
  ca:
   path:C:\path_to_cert.crt
```

and it is also not working with  this to the system environment variables:

```
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=C:\cert.crt
```

So, how can i put a certificate to antora-playbook.yml or anywhere else in my documentation project? Right now all ends up in a 400 Error when using command:
antora antora-playbook.yml

Answer (score 1):

ok, got a solution:
create a .js-file, i.e. app.js with content:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require("axios");
const { exec } = require("child_process")

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
port: 1234,
key: fs.readFileSync("C:\\cert.pem"),
cert: fs.readFileSync("C:\\cert.crt"),
pfx: fs.readFileSync('C:\\cert.pfx'),
passphrase: 'password',
form: {
    //credentials GitLab
    username: "username",
    password: "password"
}
 })
axios.get('https://gitlab.x.info/users/sign_in', {
    httpsAgent
}).then(res=>{
    console.log(res.status)
    **exec("npm run-script antora")**
}).catch(res=> {
    console.log(res)
})
```

and in package json put:

```
 "scripts": {
   "antora": "antora antora-playbook.yml"
  }
```

it is ONE way.There might be other ways to got it work.